# router-outlet works incorrect

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

Component that loading Router is rendering outside router-outlet
app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector  : "body",
    template  : `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {path: "/auth/login", name: "Auth", component: AuthComponent},
    {path: "/...", name: "Default", component: DefaultComponent}
])
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _router: Router) {
    }
}
```

default.component.ts

```
@Component({
    template  : `
    <header-view></header-view>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
`,
    directives: [HeaderComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {path: "/", name: "LevelsList", component: LevelListComponent, useAsDefault: true}
])
export class DefaultComponent {
    constructor(private _router: Router) {}
}
```

Console has no error. While inspecting an element I see that router-outlet is empty and component is rendering after it.

[image]

Comment: The fact that <router-outlet> child route content renders below the closing tag was driving me nuts, as it doesn't seem to be documented or discussed anywhere but here.  Thank you for asking, and thank you @Gunter for the answer.  

This question is still very difficult to find in Google results. How can we increase visibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. There is a related open issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8529 but I didn't get the impression this is something that is considered for being changed.

Comment: Then why I have an undefined element?

Comment: AFAIK this is when your component doesn't have a `selector: 'xxx'`

Comment: Works fine. Thanks